# My EmbedBuilder for my Discord Bot is not creating the message

Tags: java, exception, discord, bots, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a little problem with my bot. I want to create a "!command" to show all available commands inside an embeded Message. But if i try to run it i get the Error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

It also says, that the sendMessage-Method for the embeded message is deprecated.

Here is my Code:

public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {

    String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

    // der angegebene Member
    Member member = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0);

    // der angegebene User
    User user = event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().get(0);

    // der command für einen kick
    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "hauste")) {
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("Hauste rein " + args[1]).queue();

        sendMess(user, "Wurdest halt gekickt ");

        member.kick("Bye").queue();

        // der command für einen spam
    } else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "spam")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(args[2]); i++) {
            sendMess(user, args[3]);
        }
    } else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "commands")) {
        EmbedBuilder commands = new EmbedBuilder();
        commands.setTitle("Alle Commands", null);
        commands.setDescription(
                "1. Kick :   !kick @user" + "2. Spam :   !spam @user {Anzahl der Nachrichten} {Nachricht}");
        commands.setColor(Color.red);

        event.getChannel().sendMessage(commands.build()).queue();
    }

}

/**
 * Extra Methode um dem User eine Nachricht zu schicken
 * 
 * @param user Der angegebene User
 * @param text Der gewünschte Text
 */
public void sendMess(User user, String text) {
    user.openPrivateChannel().queue((channel) -> {
        channel.sendMessage(text).queue();
    });
}
```

}

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Finn

Comment: If nobody is mentioned your `get(0)` will throw.

Comment: @Minn how would you check for it? Right now i do it like this: if (!event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().isEmpty()
     && !event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().isEmpty())

Comment: @Minn but when I code i constantly get freezes. Does it come from that if-clause?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if the message contains \s+ and if not just return or send an error message in the chat